# Can't retrieve from double HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, hashmap

I'm trying to make a 16 by 16 by 16 containing a value for each point.
Each point is a 16 bit integer(short).

I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Chunk.getBlock(Chunk.java:42)
    at Foo.main(ChunkTest.java:12)
```

Heres my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Chunk {
    private HashMap<Byte, HashMap<Byte, Short>> tiles = new HashMap<Byte, HashMap<Byte, Short>>();

    public Chunk() {
        HashMap<Byte, Short> tile;

        //Create 16 tiles
        for(byte i = 0; i<16;i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            tile = new HashMap<Byte, Short>();

            //Fills the tile with the default value, 1
            for(short e = 0; e<256;e++) {
                System.out.println(e);
                tile.put((byte) e, (short) 1);
            }

            tiles.put(i, tile);

        }
    }

    //Should return the id(short) at the specified coordinates.
    public short getBlock(byte x, byte y, byte z) {
        HashMap<Byte, Short> tile = tiles.get(y);

        short block = tile.get(x+(z*16)); //Line 42

        return block;
    }

}
```

I've read my code like 5 times, and I still can't figure out what is wrong. As far as I have read, it should be possible to make a double HashMap.

So how do I make one, and retrieve it's values?

Comment: Why aren't you using `int`s everywhere instead of `short`s and `byte`s?

Comment: Because I don't need higher values, and this code is going to be ran like 8 thousand times.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil, some say..

Comment: Yeah. It turned out to be in this case, but look how much memory I saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tile.get( x+(z*16) );
```

This expression `x+(z*16)` will have all its operands converted to `int` because of numeric promotion. So what happens is that since [`Map#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) takes `Object` as a parameter, the result gets boxed to `Integer`. An `Integer` is never equal to a `Byte`, despite being numerically equivalent, since there is a type check too.

Try this instead:

```
tile.get((byte) ( x+(z*16) ));
```

That should work, assuming the result is always between 0 and 255. (But note that casting converts values greater than 127 to negative numbers, since `byte` is signed.)

---

As a suggestion to think about, if your tile index values always fall in such a small range, you could consider just using an array as a table instead of a `Map`.

Something like:

```
short[][] tiles = new short[16][256];

for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    for (int e = 0; e < 256; ++e)
        tiles[i][e] = 1;
```

You avoid boxing conversion and numeric promotion issues. Whether it's better or not depends on what you're doing and whether you're going to use operations besides `put`/`get`.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'm feeling pretty dumb now.

Do you have any idea why my IDE didn't told me I needed to cast it? I'm using the latest version of Eclipse.

Comment: Some IDEs will give you a warning for this, but it's not required. A quick test using my IDE (Netbeans) shows that I get a warning when passing an `Integer` explicitly, but not when it's the result of boxing.